# Is there anyway to get android app icon, app name and app description using app package name?

Tags: android, google-api-js-client, android-management-api

How can I get the android app name, app info and app icon from app package name?
Is any API available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide a UI for customers to search apps, upload private apps and web apps, and organize apps. I would suggest checking out the [Managed Google Play iFrame](https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps#managed_google_play_iframe).

You can get the app name, app title, etc. by using [applications.get()](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications/get) method. This method returns an [Applications resource](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications). Unfortunately, app info and icon isn’t included in the applications resource but there may be other APIs available outside Android Management API that return these fields.